# Why can't we format question titles?

Tags: discussion, formatting, titles

It would be nice if italics were possible in question titles; is there a reason why we aren't able to?

Comment: Why the downvote?  Is the answer so obvious?

Comment: Downvoting on Meta indicates disagreement. Probably someone who doesn't want italics in titles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Question titles are likely to end up in place where formatting is in-appropriate or technically impossible such as news feeds, the multi-colider, popup question notifiers, chat messages, etc. If a given title relies on formatting clues to make sense the alternate display locations will be less usable. It is better to rely on punctuation and good phrasing to make the title clear.

Comment: I didn't even think about where the titles sometimes end up - thanks for the info!

Comment: the math / physics sites have this issue as well, though it's arguably more defensible. Even there we encourage people to avoid "all math markup" titles when possible.